# How to setup Nginx on Amazon EC2 (running Ubuntu Lucid) and configure for FastCGI/FastCGI C++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, fastcgi

I am building a C++ API which I want to provide as a web service. I am thinking of using the REST API and have decided to use either FastCGI or FastCGI C++ to communicate between the C++ API and the web server.

This is a very high traffic web service, and I am going to setup an Nginx server to handle the load. Is there a tutorial I can follow to install Nginx on Amazon EC2 (running Ubuntu Lucid) and configure to work with either FastCGI or FastCGI C++?

Answer (score 2):

How about this blog setting up Nginx on Ubuntu Amazon EC2 with PHP-FPM:

http://blog.johnalvero.com/2010/12/canonical-ubuntu-1010-on-amazon-ec2.html